# Python ImportError in shell

Tags: python

```
Bar
 +-Foo
 |  +-Foo.py
 |  +-__init__.py 
 +-main.py
```

with Foo.py containing

```
class Foo
   ...
```

in main.py

```
 from Foo.Foo import Foo
```

When I execute

```
python main.py
```

in the directory `Bar`

I get the error

```
ImportError: No module named Foo.Foo
```

But when I just run the python interpreter in the Bar folder and type

```
from Foo.Foo import Foo
```

then I do not get an error.

Comment: It works for me. Your error must be something else. Try starting from an empty directory, reproducing the steps, then compare the two directories and see what's different.

Comment: Where are you running the script from? Is Foo on your python path?

Comment: Im running the script from the Bar folder. My problem might be that I don't know that a python path is :)

Comment: The following commands, `mkdir -p Bar/Foo; touch Bar/Foo/__init__.py; printf '%s\n' 'class Foo: pass' >Bar/Foo/Foo.py; printf '%s\n' 'from Foo.Foo import Foo' >Bar/main.py; (cd Bar && exec python main.py)` produce the environment you describe above, yet works perfectly for me. Thus, this question description doesn't contain enough information to reproduce the stated problem.

Comment: the problem is in the ... :)

Comment: (If you'd created and tested a reproducer, then you'd know *exactly* which elements were involved and necessary to produce the problem, rather than needing to guess -- in this case, wrongly, and thus failing to include some portion thereof).

Comment: @user695652, re: "what a python path is" -- look at the contents of `sys.path` when inside the Python interpreter to determine where modules are loaded from, and the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable as a possible means by which the above is overridden.